# Why does my .htaccess RewriteRule works perfectly on DreamHost but produces Internal Server Error on GoDaddy?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-//]+)$ index.php?go=$1&extras=$2 [L]  
#/dashboard/test/1/2/3/4 converts to $_GET['go'] = 'dashboard' and $_GET['extras'] = 'test/1/2/3/4'
```

I had this perfectly working on my DreamHost server but when I transferred my app to my GoDaddy server, it produces a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: possible because it is disabled by default ?

Comment: Whay do you mean disabled? I got this code working on GoDaddy RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?go=$1 but not the code above which the one I need.

Comment: Then if it is working check the logs to see what it is going on with the above one will help you to fix it

Comment: I have this on top of my .htaccess Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Comment: try scaping this `/` becomes `\/` would look like this: `([A-Za-z0-9-\/]+)`

Comment: I already tried that too, still doesn't work :(

Comment: Well then I go back to my previous recommendation take a look at the error log or rewrite log from your domain it might lead you to what the problem is.

Comment: I have this on my server log `[Sun Mar 13 20:03:48 2011] [error] [client 121.54.54.49] mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.`

Comment: I belive your problem is at `//`, for some reason that is producing enough redirections to hit the limit what is the url you have with the max amount of fields like your example ? maybe you should use the `RewriteOptions MaxRedirects` to increase it to above your field amount.

Comment: I tried `RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=50` but it still doesn't work. I only need like this `http://hostname/dashboard/a/b/c` where `dashboard` tells which page to include and `a\b\c` goes to `$_GET['extras']` which I have to explode after.

Answer (score 0):

The server on godaddy has probably not got mod_rewrite enabled.

Put this in the `.htaccess` file and remove everything else:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

If mod_rewrite is disabled, you will still get a 500 server error...

Comment: I'm pretty sure mod_rewrite is enabled because I got this code working

 `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?go=$1` 

I have this on top of my .htaccess

`Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /`

I just don't know why this code

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-//]+)$ index.php?go=$1&extras=$2 [L] `

works on DreamHost but not on GoDaddy. Both server has mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try the codes written below in your .htaccess file. I am sure it will work out.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-//]+)$ index.php?go=$1&extras=$2     [L]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-//]+)$ index.php?go=$1&extras=$2    [PT,L,QSA]
```

let me know if it worked for you. thanks...

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving your time :) but your code still produces 500 Internal Server Error and this error log `mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.`

Comment: i also dont know the specific reason on this error. But the code i supplied is which used on my godaddy hosting account and it worked fine for me. although I heard it kind of shared hosting problem. Anyways did u try the commented line the code, trying uncommenting the line which is commented right now. And BTW, godaddy takes sometime to read the changes on htaccess files...  :)

Comment: Yeah I'm on shared hosting and tried the commented line of code but same results. The first time I tried my code above on GoDaddy I waited more than 24 hours for the server to read the changes but no luck. Maybe the problem really is because I'm on shared hosting, this sucks :( anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: np. just the main code that makes it happen is "Options -MultiViews" so try altering your RewriteRule and I am sure it should work. :)